# Do you "solve" a non-financial deficit? "Cure" it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a list of things that are wrong with a training program. I put them in Column 1 and titled that column "Deficits" (deficit: a lack, shortage, or disadvantage). For example:

- Training is too long
- Training does not address associates' fear of
  selling
- Training is boring

In Column 2, I have listed ways to address each deficit. For example:

- Create smaller chunks
- Add training to help associates get comfortable with selling
- Make it engaging

If Column 1 is titled "Deficits," what is Column 2's title? "Cures"? "Solutions"? "Fixes"?

I'm sure there is a better word. I just can't think of it.

Comment: I would rename the columns as **problems** and **solutions**. We don't really use "deficit" like that, it is usually financial, although someone or something might be described as "deficient".

Comment: I tend to agree with @WeatherVane, but there are those who will never use the word "problems" as some have likened it to an act of surrender. The management-school term would be "challenges". But if you want to keep "deficits" I would head the other column "***remedies***"

Comment: Another term, instead of deficits, is “improvement opportunities.”

Comment: I can't see that "Deficits" works at all - A deficit is a quantity below zero. You could use "***Deficiencies***" or ***Shortcomings***".

Comment: "deficit" in this context is a metaphor, and you risk mixing your metaphors if you try and expand on it.

Comment: 'Fixes' seems the best fit, if one is allowed informal terms. Though perhaps one should be less arrogative, more hedged:  _potential_ fixes / solutions.

Comment: Solve suggests finding a solution, while cure or fix suggest remedying a problem, correct suggests fixing an error, etc. you probably want something more generic.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to keep the "Deficit" heading, then the other heading could be "Correction"

Answer (score 0):

Weather Vane commented:

> I would rename the columns as **problems** and **solutions.** We don't really use "deficit" like that, it is usually financial, although someone or something might be described as "deficient".